# How do I rotate a Quaternion with 2nd Quaternion on its local or world axes without using transform.Rotate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, quaternions

[`Transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) has a very helpful interface for selecting whether or not a rotation should be made relative to world axes or the local axes.

Behind the scenes, it's doing some math to the transform's `rotation`, a `Quaternion`, with another `Quaternion`. And the exact nature of this math changes depending on if you choose the local or world flag.

How can I do this sort of math without assigning the first `Quaternion` to a Transform's `rotation` (wasting memory and/or time) just to do some math with it?

Suppose my first `Quaternion` is `Quaternion q1 = Quaternion.Euler(0f,0f,90f);` and the second is `Quaternion q2 = Quaternion.Euler(90f,0f,0f)`.

Applying the second to the first along its local axes would give a rotation that rotates its right side to face down and its front to face right.

Applying the second to the first along the original axes would give a rotation that rotates its back to face down and its top to face right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Use the [`Quaternion operator *`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html).

In Unity, when you multiply two quaternions, it applies the second quaternion (expressed in global axes) to the first quaternion (along the local axes produced after the first `Quaternion`).

So, **if you want to do the equivalent of `Rotate(q2, Space.Self)`, where `q1` is the transform's original `rotation`, and `q3` is the transform's new `rotation`, you want `Quaternion q3 =  q1 * q2`.**

---

What do you do if you want to apply `q2` to `q1` along the axes before `q1` applies (i.e., along the global axes)? Well, it turns out that is equivalent to applying `q1` along the local axes of `q2`.

As an example, applying `q2` along the global axes of `q1` rotates its back to face down and its top to face right. Consider that that applying `q1` along the local axes of `p2` also rotates its back to face down and its top to face right. They result in the same orientation!

So what does that mean? **If you want to apply `q2` to `q1` along the axes before `q1` applies, then do `Quaternion q3 = q2 * q1`.**

**This is the equivalent of doing `Rotate(q2, Space.World)` where `q1` is the transform's original `rotation`, and `q3` is the new `rotation`.**

---

Unlike `Rotate`, you can use this operator to rotate an object relative to its parent's axes! If you do `transform.localRotation = q2 * transform.localRotation`, you will be rotating the object relative to the axis of the parent.

Comment: Credit to Owen-Reynolds for writing [this answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/810719/view.html) on the Unity Q&A site that really helped me understand this operator.