# Relative quaternion when all 3 euler axis are variable

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

I have some objects in a 3D Unity scene orbiting a large sphere which is at Vector3.Zero. They can move in any direction perpendicular to the surface and they face the direction of their travel:

[image]

I set their rotation to be perpendicular every frame by calculating the surface normal on the sphere under them and using Quaternion.LookRotation:

```
perpendicularRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.Cross(transform.right, normal), normal);
rigidbody.MoveRotation(perpendicularRotation);
```

This works nicely to ensure they always orbit the sphere with the bottom of the shapes facing the surface of the sphere.

What I can't figure out is how to add a bit more rotation, specifically I would like the front of the shapes to point 45 degrees down as they move (think of a helicopter as it moves forwards - the nose points down to increase speed):

[image]

Basically what I'm looking to do is create a rotation in the shape's local space. If they were perfectly aligned Vector3.forward in a single frame I'd do something like:

```
newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(45, 0, 0) * rigidBody.Rotation
```

But since their euler angles are all over the place thanks to the perpendicular rotation and since I need this to a fixed rotation (i.e. it doesn't keep spinning 45 deg every frame, just holds 45 deg as it moves along) I'm not sure how to add a downward rotation in their relative direction. I'm OK handling the movement in the original 'forwards' direction once the rotation is worked out.

I've tried so many combinations of Quaternion & Vector3 methods its hard to remember them all and probably not worth posting a wall of useless commented out code here! I think I've probably been overcomplicating this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I rotate a Quaternion with 2nd Quaternion on its local or world axes without using transform.Rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246893/how-do-i-rotate-a-quaternion-with-2nd-quaternion-on-its-local-or-world-axes-with). Use `newRotation = rigidbody.Rotation  * Quaternion.Euler(45f,0,0);`

Comment: or rather `newRotation = perpendicularRotation * Quaternion.Euler(-x,0,0); rigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);` where `x` is some value clamped between `0` and `45` depending on how fast the ship is going.

Comment: Yeah thanks. As it happens I'd actually tried that but was visualising it with DrawRay which I did wrong!