# How to rotate an object around itself?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I want to rotate a cube in Unity3D.When I push arrow left button on keyboard the cube have to rotate left.If I push up, the cube have to rotate up.But with my script the cube rotate left and then the left-side rotate up.

**This is the current status:**

[image]

**That's what I want:**

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float smooth = 1f;
    private Quaternion targetRotation;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        targetRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
            targetRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.right);
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
            targetRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.left);
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
            targetRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.up);
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
            targetRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.down);
        }
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, 10* smooth * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You need to swap the order of your quaternion multiplication.

The way you have it now, the rotations are applied to the axes as they would be after the original rotation because you are effectively doing `targetRotation = targetRotation * ...;`.

However, you want to rotate the rotation around the world axes. You can do this by doing `targetRotation = ... * targetRotation;`:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
        targetRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.right) * targetRotation;
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
        targetRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.left) * targetRotation;
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
        targetRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.up) * targetRotation;
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
        targetRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.down) * targetRotation;
    }
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, 10* smooth * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

See [How do I rotate a Quaternion with 2nd Quaternion on its local or world axes without using transform.Rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246893/how-do-i-rotate-a-quaternion-with-2nd-quaternion-on-its-local-or-world-axes-with) for more information.