# Averaging an array of rotations and using them to apply torque

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm building a VR interaction system, and adding a throwing component.

It's set up so that I have a continually updating array of positions for the held object, and when I release the held object it calculates the delta positions for each of the time steps between those last 5 positions and averages them. This leaves me with a smooth throw vector for impulse force without any jitters introduced from an unintentional wrist flick on release. This system is implemented and works great.

I'm now trying to do the same thing with rotations and adding a torque force on release. **However**, with my current implementation it seems like it just picks a random axis to rotate on upon release.

I have my updating array of quaternions implemented the same way as the positions, no problem there, the issue is either in my quaternion averaging code, or my delta rotation calculation code:

The following is my method for calculating delta rotations. Note that `rotations` is the array of `n` rotations from the last frames, most recent at `0` and oldest at `n`

```
Quaternion[] deltaRotations = new Quaternion[rotations.Length - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < deltaRotations.Length; i++)
{
    deltaRotations[i] = Quaternion.Inverse(rotations[i]) * rotations[i+1];
}
```

The following is my method for averaging the delta rotations.

```
Quaternion avgRot = Quaternion.identity;

int quatCount = 0;

foreach (Quaternion quat in deltaRotations)
{
    quatCount ++;
    avgRot = Quaternion.Slerp(avgRot, quat, 1 / quatCount);
}
```

The resulting forces from `Rigidbody.addTorque(avgRot, ForceMode.Impulse)` set it rotating in a seemingly random directions.

Anything jumping out at you guys as blatantly wrong?

EDIT

Per Ruzihim's answer, I have converted the code to use angle / axis representations of rotations and average those. This nails the proper axis for rotation upon object's release, but seems to give me the same strength of rotation every time. Code for the new calculate rotation force method below, not that I'm passing the array of deltaRotations into this function rather than passing in the raw rotations array and calculating the delta rotations after the fact:

```
    Vector3 averageRotationsAngleAxis(Quaternion[] rotations) // returns an angle / axis representation of averaged rotations[]
    {
        Vector3[] deltaAxes = new Vector3[rotations.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < rotations.Length; i++)
        {
            float angle;
            Vector3 axis;
            rotations[i].ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis);

            deltaAxes[i] = angle * axis;
        }

        Vector3 returnVec = averageVector3(deltaAxes);

        return returnVec;
    }
```

Marking Ruzihim's answer as correct, when I `Debug.Log` the result of the throw rotations using his method they come out looking right, the problem must be somewhere in between that and the impulse torque

Comment: Can you post the array of rotations you are using?  You for loop is going one more than it should.  Change deltaRotations.Length to deltaRotations.Length - 1 since you have i and (i + 1).

Comment: @jdweng `deltaRotations.Length` = `rotations.Length - 1`. That part looks fine to me, I imagine the OP would have a runtime exception if that were an issue

Comment: @jdweng you might be onto something here, I'm trying to Debug.Log the array of rotations and its only ever showing one rather than the set of 5 i was expecting.

But yes the array length is fine, its rotations.Length - 1 because there are 4 delta rotations between 5 rotations

Comment: Alright I've cleared up the too few quaternions issue, but have the same problem, here's a set of typical quaternions coming that are being fed into the delta converting and averaging code:

(-0.02236, 0.02097, -0.04850, 0.99835)
(-0.01765, 0.03755, -0.03795, 0.9984)
(-0.01765, 0.03755, -0.03795, 0.99867)
(-0.01576, 0.03766, -0.03136, 0.99867)
(-0.02256, 0.03473, -0.02588, 0.99880)

Comment: This might work if you calculate the deltas along global axes with `deltaRotation = rotations[i+1] * Quaternion.Inverse(rotations[i])` instead of `deltaRotations[i] = Quaternion.Inverse(rotations[i]) * rotations[i+1]`. I'm not 100% about the use of slerp to "average" them, so I provided an alternative as an answer below.

Comment: Actually, is `rotations[0]` the most recent rotation? Or is it the least recent rotation? I assume the least recent...

Comment: @Andrew Williamson  It is not the exception, it is the fact the average would change.

Comment: The numbers look very small and seem to be a small vibration which would appear in results as random data.  So I do not think there is anything wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using slerp to average quaternions can result in some unexpected behaviours. For instance, if you have 2 delta rotations, one of 180 degrees around the y axis and one of -180 degrees around the y axis, slerping from one to the other would never produce an identity rotation(a rotation of 0 degrees arund the y axis). it would actually always be a 180 degree rotation in some direction. Try it yourself:

```
Quaternion a = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180f, Vector3.up); 
Quaternion b = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-180f, Vector3.up); 
Quaternion c = Quaternion.Slerp(a, b, 0.5f)

float angle; 
Vector3 axis; 
c.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis); 
Debug.Log(angle); 
Debug.Log(axis);
```

So, instead, I would recommend averaging the axis & angle of rotation, specifically using the *global* axes of rotation. To get the delta rotations in global axes, start with [`global axis delta rotation * start rotation = next rotation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56246894/1092820) and solve algebraically:

```
                globalAxesDelta * startRot = nextRot
globalAxesDelta * startRot * inv(startRot) = nextRot * inv(startRot)
                           globalAxesDelta = nextRot * inv(startRot)
```

So to calculate the rotation deltas using global axes, use `deltaRotation = rotations[i+1] * Quaternion.Inverse(rotations[i])` instead of `deltaRotations[i] = Quaternion.Inverse(rotations[i]) * rotations[i+1]`. Then, convert them to axis/angle form using [`ToAngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.ToAngleAxis.html):

```
Vector3[] deltaAxes = new Vector3[rotations.Length - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < deltaRotations.Length; i++)
{
    Quaternion deltaRotation = rotations[i+1] * Quaternion.Inverse(rotations[i]);
    float angle;  
    Vector3 axis;
    deltaRotation.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis);
    deltaAxes[i] = angle * axis;
}
```

Then average these global axes:

```
Vector3 avgAxis = Vector3.zero;

foreach (Vector3 angleAxis in deltaAxes)
{
    avgAxis += (1f/deltaRotations.Length) * angleAxis;
}
```

Then you would apply the torque using something like `AddTorque(avgAxis * someTorqueFactor)` to apply it along global axes.

Comment: Flipping `deltaRotations[i] = Quaternion.Inverse(rotations[i]) * rotations[i+1]` to `deltaRotation = rotations[i+1] * Quaternion.Inverse(rotations[i])` was half the problem, thank you! While I implement the angle / axis averaging method, do you have a laymans explanation as to why averaging quaternions isn't a viable approach?

Comment: Well, slerp for sure is not the best way to go about it.  If you have 2 delta rotations, one of 180 degrees around the y axis and one of -180 degrees around the y axis, slerping from one to the other would never produce an identity rotation(a rotation of 0 degrees arund the y axis). it would actually always be a 180 degree rotation in some direction.

Comment: Try it yourself: `float angle;`
`Vector3 axis;`
`Quaternion a = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180f, Vector3.up);`
`Quaternion b = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-180f, Vector3.up);`

`Quaternion c = Quaternion.Slerp(a, b, 0.5f);`
`c.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis);`
`Debug.Log(angle);`
`Debug.Log(axis);`

Comment: I have no idea if averaging quaternions algebraically - adding up each of their components and dividing by the number of terms - would consistently produce anything helpful, but it might. I think averaging the axis-angle representation is more intuitive either way.

Comment: Agreed, the angle / axis method is much better to look at. I've implemented it and it's working perfectly for determining the axis it should be rotating on, but it seems it's now giving me the same force no matter how fast I turn my hand. Weird that the averaging function would average the axes properly, but not the strength, any idea why?

Comment: @WyattWehking It should take into account the angle of rotation at this point here:     `deltaAxes[i] = angle * axis;`... Not sure why not :(

Comment: Yeah it doesn't make sense to me either, I've edited the post to show the updated method for calculating average rotation, I'll keep experimenting but let me know if you spot anything in there.

Comment: Even weirder it doesn't seem to be affected by the rotation force multiplier, whether i multiply by 1 or 100 it still leaves my hands rotating at the same speed...

Answer (score 1):

In general regarding `Quaternion` really listen to [`Ruzihm`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62786131/7111561)! ^^

---

As an alternative afaik you could also average the Euler angles like

```
Quaternion[] deltaRotations = new Quaternion[rotations.Length - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < deltaRotations.Length; i++)
{
    deltaRotations[i] = Quaternion.Inverse(rotations[i]) * rotations[i+1];
}

var averageEuler = Vector3.zero;
foreach(var rot in deltaRotations)
{
    averageEuler += rot.eulerAngles;
}
averageEuler /= deltaRotations.Length;


return Quaternion.Euler(averageEuler);
```

This should afaik also solve this issue with `180` vs `-180` degrees since the Unity API already "normalizes" the `eulerAngles`.

---

**Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear .. and actually works that way ;)**

Comment: Euler angles method is definitely better than slerp. I think this will produce different results, but I don't know for sure, and this way may feel better ^^. I hope asker tries both methods and gives feedback on if they feel different in game