# Set rotation along Vector3 axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, quaternions

I'm building a controller with an arbitrary sense of "down", such that I can't use normal methods of camera movement.

I can move the camera on the up / right axes fine, but this creates unwanted "roll". I've looked around / tried a lot but can't find a good method of setting this camera rotation on an arbitrary "forward" axis without screwing up the other movement.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [quaternion multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56246894/1092820) to rotate the camera around the arbitrary up axis (you can use [Quaternion.AngleAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html) to find this) and its local x axis according to the relevant input (mouse used here as example):

```
Vector3 myUp = Vector3.up; // set with arbitrary up
float rotationSpeed = 1f;

// ...

float horizMouseMove = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed;
float vertMouseMove = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeed
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(horizMouseMove, myUp) 
        * transform.rotation 
        * Quaternion.EulerAngles(-vertMouseMove, 0f, 0f);
```

Comment: THANK YOU

I had to modify slightly for my case (another AngleAxis for the last line) because it needed to be relative to my arbitrary down, but this now works without roll. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: @JordanCarroll The last line has more to do with the left/right axis... can you explain what you mean? Please feel welcome to edit my answer to include the change you made