# Unity3D Adjusting CUBE "endRotation" on right ( x or z) axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I am new in Unity3D scripting especially when it comes to specifics of Transform, Quaternions, Vector3.
Down there is a script. When I roll the cube it flips in the right direction. However when cubes' local axis doesn't match the world axis the cube's `endRotation` is performed on the wrong axis.
*Can anybody help me to resolve this issue **: "endRotation"** would flip the cube on right axis* regardless of the relation between `LOCAL axis <=> WorldAxis`.
I was trying to resolve it for a week. Of cause no success.
Further down there code and video.

```
      if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > buttonDown)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FlipTheCube(Vector3.right));
            return
        }...
```

.
.
.

```
    public IEnumerator FlipTheCube(Vector3 direction)
{
    startFliping = false;

    float rollStartTime = 0;
    float rollAngle = 90;
    float halfWidth = transform.localScale.z / 2;
    Vector3 pointAround = transform.position + (Vector3.down * halfWidth) + (direction * halfWidth);
    Vector3 rollAxis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, direction);

    Quaternion rotation = transform.rotation;
    Quaternion **endRotation** = rotation * Quaternion.Euler(rollAxis * rollAngle);
    Vector3 endPlacement = transform.position + direction;

    float oldAngle = 0;

    while (rollStartTime < rollDurtnTime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        rollStartTime += Time.deltaTime;
        float newAngle = (rollStartTime / rollDurtnTime) * rollAngle;
        float rotateThrough = newAngle - oldAngle;
        oldAngle = newAngle;

        transform.RotateAround(pointAround, rollAxis, rotateThrough);
    }

    transform.position = endPlacement;
    transform.rotation = **endRotation**;

    startFliping = true;
}
```

[Here is a link to the youtube video
**First part of video** If cubes local axis is matching world axis the "endRotation" is flipping correctly **Second part of video** as soon cubes local axis is not matching world axis "endRotation" goes wrong.](https://youtu.be/RjEgCu5JcBs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems lie within these lines:

```cs
Vector3 rollAxis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, direction);

Quaternion rotation = transform.rotation;
Quaternion endRotation = rotation * Quaternion.Euler(rollAxis * rollAngle);

// ...

    transform.RotateAround(pointAround, rollAxis, rotateThrough);
```

---

#### First problem is Euler vs angle/axis usage.

If you've only been rotating against `Vector3.right`, `Vector3.forward`, and their negatives you might not have even noticed this yet.

In the first part, you use `rollAxis` as an Euler angle representation, and in the second part as an axis.

The problem is that for a rotation, its axis is **usually not** the same as a Euler representation of that rotation! For example, the rotation made by rotating around (0.7, 0.0, 0.7) by 90° is completely different from an Euler rotation of (63°, 0°, 63°)!

Instead, just use `rollAxis` consistently as an angle/axis representation. You can get the quaternion form using [`Quaternion.AngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html).

---

#### Second problem is global vs local rotation.

This is a problem whose effects you're definitely already noticing.

In the first part, you apply `rollAxis` as a local rotation. This is because `rollAxis` is the second term of the `*` operator.

In the second part, `RotateAround` rotates around a global axis defined by `rollAxis`.

Keep it global or local for both. Global is simpler, and it *appears* that's what you're trying to do (judging from `transform.position + direction`), so you should have `rotation` as the second term of the `*` operator.

---

Altogether, the problems can be fixed by just changing the `Quaternion endRotation = rotation * Quaternion.Euler(rollAxis * rollAngle);` line:

```cs
Vector3 rollAxis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, direction);

Quaternion rotation = transform.rotation;
Quaternion endRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rollAngle, rollAxis) * rotation;

// ...

    transform.RotateAround(pointAround, rollAxis, rotateThrough);
```

---

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56246893/1092820) for more information about the quaternion `*` operator.

Comment: Thank you, it's jus me being not that experienced. However BIG THANK YOU.

Comment: ...and thank you for posting ref link about * operator

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you using DoTween asset (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/dotween-hotween-v2-27676):

`DORotate(Vector3 to, float duration);`

[image: Rotations]

Using tweeners will save you a lot of time writing your own animations.

Comment: Asker is asking how to get the quaternion one would use as the `to` parameter. So unfortunately, this answer does not really help.